# is staff is not updating in Django-allauth custom signup form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

i created a custom form from the Django-allauth package adding a first name, Lastname and is_staff. This was after i had extended the user model using abstart user. i think it has something to do with is_staff being a boolean value. All suggestions are welcome. thank you.

My user model looks like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    # first_name= models.CharField( blank=False, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

My custom form is as shown below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    is_staff = forms.BooleanField(required=True ,label = 'Are you been assigned as a staff?')
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your signup method and add the following line before save,

```py
user.is_staff = self.cleaned_data['is_staff']
```

Comment: I did this,  still not working,  not sure if it's possible to clean a boolean value